# NPM install stuck in a loop

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Every time I try to use npm install command in the vsc terminal I get hit with this error:

```
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
[..................] | idealTree:inflate:node_modules/acorn-jsx: sill inflate node_modules/acorn-jsx
```

And it just goes on forever, I think it's a loop cause afterwards I just get fetch errors.

Comment: You should probably share those fetch errors you're getting too.

Comment: May be a relevant issue: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4028

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue today and it turned out to be a connection issue. Had to disconnect from VPN!